# Group by IDs and TIMESTAMPDIFF one column in same table

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, datediff

I am trying to find out "how many unique messages has been sent to a person on a specific boat within a timeframe, and what is the minimum days between those texts" and display it including the count.

*A person is represented by 'id', boat by 'id2' and message by 'text'.*

```
CREATE TABLE `stacktable` (
`timestamp` DATETIME NOT NULL,
`id` VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
`id2` VARCHAR(3) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`text` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`id3` INT(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
PRIMARY KEY (`id3`)
);

insert into stacktable (timestamp,id,id2,text) VALUES
('2015-01-01 00:00:01',1,10,'ABC'),
('2015-01-01 00:00:01',2,11,'ABC'),
('2015-01-01 00:00:01',3,12,'ABC'),
('2015-01-01 00:00:02',3,12,'ABC'),
('2015-01-01 00:00:02',1,10,'ABC'),
('2015-01-04 00:00:01',1,10,'ABC'),
('2015-01-04 00:00:01',1,10,'BCD'),
('2015-01-04 00:00:01',2,11,'ABC'),
('2015-01-04 00:00:01',2,11,'BCD'),
('2015-01-04 00:00:01',3,12,'ABC'),
('2015-01-04 00:00:01',3,12,'BCD'),
('2015-01-04 00:00:01',3,13,'CDE'),
('2015-01-07 00:00:01',2,11,'BCD'),
('2015-01-07 00:00:01',3,12,'BCD'),
('2015-01-07 00:00:01',3,13,'CDE'),
('2015-01-07 00:00:01',3,13,'DEF'),
('2015-01-08 00:00:01',3,12,'ABC'),
('2015-01-08 00:00:01',4,14,'EFG'),
('2015-01-09 00:00:01',4,14,'EFG'),
('2015-01-09 00:00:02',4,15,'FGH'),
('2015-01-10 00:00:01',4,14,'EFG'),
('2015-01-10 00:00:01',4,14,'FGH'),
('2015-01-10 00:00:01',4,15,'FGH'),
('2015-01-11 00:00:01',4,14,'EFG'),
('2015-01-15 00:00:01',4,14,'EFG');
```

To show what I am trying to achieve:

```
select * from stacktable where id = 1

timestamp           id id2 text id3     
2015-01-01 00:00:01 1  10  ABC  1    First entry for id+id2+text (ABC)
2015-01-01 00:00:02 1  10  ABC  5    Second entry for same keys id+id2+text 1 second later
2015-01-04 00:00:01 1  10  ABC  6    Third entry for same keys id+id2+text 2 days later
2015-01-04 00:00:01 1  10  BCD  7    First entry for id+id2+text (BCD)
```

I only want to count records that has "same id,id2 and text within a period of 2 days", but also show the "minimum diffdate in days between the hits".

The output I want from this would be:

```
id id2 text count(*) mindiffdatebetweenhits
-------------------------------------------
1  10  ABC  3        0                      count id3s 1,5 and 6, minimumdaydiff is between id3 1 and 5 = 0 days
3  12  ABC  3        0                      count id3s 3,4 and 10, minimumdaydiff is between id3 3 and 4 = 0 days
4  14  EFG  4        1                      count id3s 18,19,21 and 24, minimumdaydiff is equal between all hits = 1 day
4  15  FGH  2        0                      count id3s 20 and 23, minimumdaydiff is between id3 20 and 23 = 0 days
```

How can I get the desired output?

Comment: Are you sure this will be your output?Cause time diff between id3 = 6 and 1 is more than 2 days.

Comment: I want it to count 3 for id=1 (id3 1,5,6). This is because id3 1 and id3 5 <= 2 days and id3 5 and id3 6 <= 2. SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(day, '2015-01-01 00:00:02', '2015-01-04 00:00:01') from dual = 2 - I want to "check for those with same id,id2,text within 2 days from last hit"

Comment: records 3 and 4 have date 2015-01-01 and record 10, 2015-01-04. So, more than 2 days in between. Yet you want to count 3 records. Doesn't seem consistent with "within 2 days from last hit"

Comment: Sorry. Within 2 days from 'last' hit on id+id2+text, not continuously check for timediff from first hit, rather from closest before.. Change it 1 second and you are correct, it would be 3 days.

Comment: id3 = 3  = 2015-01-01 00:00:01
id3 = 4  = 2015-01-01 00:00:02 .. 1 second later
id3 = 10 = 2015-01-04 00:00:01 .. within 2 days later.

SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(day, '2015-01-01 00:00:02', '2015-01-04 00:00:01') from dual

Comment: what should happen if you have two sequences of id,id2,text with more than 2 days in between (between latest record of sequence 1 and earliest records of sequence 2), where within each sequence your time rule applies.

Comment: Good question. Considering two sequences of same id,id2,text with more than 2 days in between the sequences, but those within and having 2 entries each, it should fetch both like 1;10;ABC;2;N and 1;10;ABC;2;N, N being the minimumdiff.

Comment: How are 01/01 and 0/4 within two days?

Comment: SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(day, '2015-01-01 00:00:02', '2015-01-04 00:00:01') from dual - That's how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it, assuming sequences of only one row are to be discarded:

```
select id, id2, text, seq, count(id) as total, min(diff) as mindiff
from (
      select t1.row, t2.row row2, t1.id, t1.id2, t1.text, t1.id3, 
             TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY, t1.timestamp, t2.timestamp) as diff,
             IF (TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY, t1.timestamp, t2.timestamp) > 2, @seq * (1 and @seq := @seq +1), @seq) as seq
      from (select (@row := @row + 1) as row, id, id2, text, id3, timestamp
            from (select   id, id2, text, id3, timestamp
                  from     stacktable
                  order by id, id2, text) sorted, 
                  (select @row := 0) setup) t1
            left join (select (@row2 := @row2 + 1) as row, id, id2, text, id3, timestamp
                       from (select id, id2, text, id3, timestamp
                             from stacktable
                             order by id, id2, text) sorted, 
                             (select @row2 := 0) setup) t2
            on  (t1.id = t2.id and t1.id2 = t2.id2 and t1.text=t2.text and t1.row = t2.row - 1),
            (select @seq := 1) setup_sequence
     ) t3
group by id, id2, text, seq
having total > 1
```

To facilitate reading, the query uses the same subquery tow times, t1 and t2, and all it does is sort and subsequently number the rows of the table:

```
select (@row := @row + 1) as row, id, id2, text, id3, timestamp
from (select   id, id2, text, id3, timestamp
      from     stacktable
      order by id, id2, text) sorted, 
     (select @row := 0) setup
```

See [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/536471/1). Note that the sequence counter is really not unique between all sequences. It's not a bug. It's only unique between sequences of same id,id2,text.

The sequence counter update is a bit tricky: @seq * (1 and @seq := @seq +1). It relies on the first @seq being set up for the multiplication before being updated. I'm not sure this is deterministic or consistent accross engines. However, the query can also be changed to avoid it by joining the records of t1 with the previous record instead of the next record (in t2). (not tried out)

Comment: What indexes would you recommend for the query above? It's getting quite heavy with all those from('s on a table with ~ 2million records

Comment: try a compound index for id, id2, text (in this order).